# Allowing cors in artisan serve

Tags: php, apache, angularjs, cors

Now after starting to learn Angularjs and Laravel 4 I just love the way one can just set up a working development server with just one terminal command without having to set up virtualhosts or anything like that.

However...

I want to develop my frontend seperately so I can utilize the wonderful combination of yeoman and gruntjs and since I really can't do this if I put everything in laravel public folder (or at least I don't know how) this leaves me with the following situation:

I have a frontend grunt server at localhost:9000

And

I have a laravel 4 server at localhost:8000

This will of course mean that in order for Angularjs to talk with Laravel I have to allow CORS.  In Apache this is easy: just adding `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "localhost:9000"` to the directory part of httpd.conf allows this url to communicate with localhost.

> Now where should I put this cors configuration when serving stuff via
>   artisan if its even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright found the answer at least one working for me.  It would seem I was approaching the problem from the wrong direction since I concentrated on Apache instead of Laravel itself.

In order to allow Cross Origin Response in a development environment via artisan the following code should be inserted in `filters.php`:

```
<?php
...
App::before(function($request)
{
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
            $statusCode = 204;

            $headers = [
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true'
            ];

            return Response::make(null, $statusCode, $headers);
        }
});


App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        return $response;
});
...
```

Also in case it is relevant I also added `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'` to Apache configation.

So now I can run my server environment in localhost:8000 and my frontend in localhost:9000 and they can talk to each other without problem.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. You can find cors configuration in `config/cors.php`. By default all origins allowed only for `api/*` routes. You can add your own routes (e.g. `oauth`) to it like following:

`'path' => ['api/*', 'oauth/*']`